# Create a full screen view over the other

Tags: android, kotlin, overlay, android-framelayout

I'm creating an Android app.

When I click on a menu item, I need to open an activity/view/fragment (I don't know what is the best). This activity/fragment/view need to be placed as an "overlay" of my app (it will have a transparent background and we could see the "regular" activity behind).

I'm using a navigation drawer and a couple of fragment inside my app.

First I tried this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AlertActivity"
    android:id="@+id/alertLayoutRoot"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="@string/mes_favoris"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </TextView>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is indeed showing my fragment, but this fragment isn't on top of all the others.

What could be the best way to do this (in working with Kotlin)?

EDIT : forgot to say, in this view, there will be a small slider.

Basicaly I want this : [Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwjvA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dialog fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment) as it supports custom layouts like fragments and shows on top of another activity or fragment.

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment) is a useful tutorial on dialog fragment.

Comment: DialogFragment is waiting for an user choice ? I forget to say, in this view, I'm going to display a small slider (to there's no "Yes,No,Cancel" possibilities)

Comment: You can use `dialog.setOnDismissListener` and then in the callback you can get the result from the dialog and continue with the execution.

Comment: Could you explain please ?